Excel table to PowerPoint Enhanced Metafile Image
I need to move multiple Excel tables into multiple powerpoints as high-resolution EMF images. I cannot link the data into powerpoint as I need to update 400+ different powerpoints from 400+ different Excel models that originate from a single Excel template and VBA is not an option. All the powerpoints and Excel models are formatted and laid out exactly the same. The code below works but the resolution of the image pasted into PowerPoint is too low and I cannot figure out how to increase it.
import win32com.client as win32
from pptx import Presentation
from PIL import ImageGrab, Image
import os

modelPath = "P:/Folder"
FileName = "XXXX.xlsx"
outT = "P:/Folder/Charts"
cellRange = 'A1:C10'
sheetName = 'Norm'

o = win32com.client.Dispatch('Excel.Application')
wb = o.Workbooks.Open(modelPath +"/"+FileName)
wsT = wb.Worksheets['Norm']

# Grab Table
wsT.Range(wsT.Cells(4,3),wsT.Cells(41,8)).CopyPicture(Format = 2)
imgEMF = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
imgFile = os.path.join(outT,'norm.emf')
imgEMF.save(imgFile, 'PNG', compress_level=0, dpi=(5000, 5000))
t=ImageGrab.grabclipboard()

# remove old tables
pres = Presentation("Test.pptx") # name of existing pptx
t = [26, 28, 31, 33, 34]

for i in t:
    slides = pres.slides[i]
    shapes = slides.shapes
    for shape in shapes:
        if shape.shape_type == 13 or shape.shape_type == 1:
            shapes.element.remove(shape.element)

#add new tables
slide = pres.slides[31]
slide.shapes.add_picture(out+'/norm.emf', left = Inches(0.41), top = Inches(2.25), width = Inches(6.17), height = Inches(3.0))
# I cut all but one table from the code

pres.save('Test6.pptx')


ImageGrab.grabclipboard() graps from clipboard an image in resolution as the cell range was in Excel GUI on screen (100% zoom). imgEMF.save(imgFile, 'PNG', compress_level=0, dpi=(5000, 5000)): Saving a PNG having file name norm.emf does not make the PNG an EMF. And dpi cannot increased to more than the source imgEMF provides.

imgEMF.save does save the file as EMF, when I look at the file properties it is saved as an EMF file

Also, I have run the file at 200% zoom to see if that changes the resolution and it does not.

Might be a crazy suggestion - but have you considered just creating a table in PPT using the data from Excel? Your dataset does not appear to be very large, so it would be quick and would give you much more control over the formatting.

This is one of twenty tables per excel model times the count noted above. The models are completely redone multiple times yearly so this unfortunately doesnt work well.
